# How to prevent ROS namespace from overwriting topic names?

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am now working on the simulation with multiple robots and I want to use namespaces to organize the nodes better. However, I am also trying some information exchange among robots so they are also subscribing to topics from others' namespaces.

Here  is the part in my launch file I start the node `send_follow_waypoints`

```
<node pkg="uuv_control_utils" type="send_follow_waypoints.py" name="$(anon name)">
    <param name="uuv_name" value="$(arg uuv_name)" />
    <param name="follow_name" value="$(arg follow_name)" />
    <param name="max_forward_speed" value="$(arg max_forward_speed)" />
    <param name="heading_offset" value="$(arg heading_offset)" />
    <param name="use_fixed_heading" value="$(arg use_fixed_heading)" />
    <param name="radius_of_acceptance" value="$(arg radius_of_acceptance)" />
    <param name="start_time" value="$(arg start_time)" />
    <param name="x_shift" value="$(arg x_shift)" />
    <param name="y_shift" value="$(arg y_shift)" />
    <param name="z_shift" value="$(arg z_shift)" />
    <param name="success_rate" value="$(arg success_rate)" />
</node>
```

And here is my subscriber inside `send_follow_waypoints.py`:

```
rospy.Subscriber('/%s/pose_gt' % follow_name,
            Odometry,
            follow_pose_callback)
```

I want the robot with `uuv_name` to subscribe to the topic `/follow_name/pose_gt`, but if I add an `ns="$(arg uuv_name)"` tag to the node, it would try to subscribe to `/uuv_name/follow_name/pose_gt`. Is there some way to stop the namespaces from changing the topic names?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367045/how-to-prevent-ros-namespace-from-overwriting-topic-names?/) by [MakinoharaShouko](https://answers.ros.org/users/55123/makinoharashouko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-12-05**:
yes, of course. But in order to tell you how we'd need to see your code and potentially launch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you have the `follow_name` argument in the launch file already, I would just remap the topic there:

```
<node pkg="uuv_control_utils" type="send_follow_waypoints.py" name="$(anon name)">
  <param name="uuv_name" value="$(arg uuv_name)" />
  <param name="follow_name" value="$(arg follow_name)" />  # Still needed?
  <param name="max_forward_speed" value="$(arg max_forward_speed)" />
  <param name="heading_offset" value="$(arg heading_offset)" />
  <param name="use_fixed_heading" value="$(arg use_fixed_heading)" />
  <param name="radius_of_acceptance" value="$(arg radius_of_acceptance)" />
  <param name="start_time" value="$(arg start_time)" />
  <param name="x_shift" value="$(arg x_shift)" />
  <param name="y_shift" value="$(arg y_shift)" />
  <param name="z_shift" value="$(arg z_shift)" />
  <param name="success_rate" value="$(arg success_rate)" />

  <remap from="follow_name/pose_gt" to="/$(arg follow_name)/pose_gt" />  # Leading slash denotes global namespace.
</node>
```

And in your node:

```
rospy.Subscriber('follow_name/pose_gt', Odometry, follow_pose_callback)
```

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0